# Drupal 7 Rest API for mobile apps

Tags: drupal-7

I have a Drupal 7 site and I want to create a mobile application that will retrieve data from my Drupal site and will also create content of a specific content type.
This content type is very simple. - It contains the following: 
* A title
* A body (long text)
* A picture (an image which has to be uploaded to the Drupal site).

I see that there are quite a few modules : restful, restws, services and more...
Which modules do you recommend for my scenario ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used [RestWS](https://www.drupal.org/project/RestWS) and Services modules.

RestWS is a simpler module providing CRUD operations for all Drupal resources (nodes, comments, users, etc) built on Entity API.

Services module provides far more functionality but may be overkill for your case. Beyond the functionality provided by RestWS it also provides support for message-oriented or RPC-style web services like SOAP, XML-RPC.
You can also configure your own 'service endpoints'.

If your requirements are simple enough then RestWS may be the most light-weight option, however if you need more configuration or customization options then Services will be the best choice.

Comment: Thanks , @Scot Anderson:   What about uploading an image from a mobile phone ? Is that also supported and can be done by RestWS ? or do I need Services as well?

Comment: @tamirko you can use this module to allow RestWS to support image upload https://www.drupal.org/project/restws_file

Comment: Thanks a lot @Scot Anderson